# Как определить версию dll и exe файла в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо в приложении проверять версию dll и exe файла (данные файлы сторонние, и не используются в самой программе) так же необходимо вывести зависимости из каждого dll и exe файла, с помощью чего это можно реализовать?

Comment: Версию NET-библиотеки? В классе Assembly - есть версия.

Comment: @nick_n_a В данном способе есть проблема, загружаемые библиотеки с помощью Assembly.Load не выгружаются из памяти, а файлов будет очень много, и вес их разнится от пары сотен килобайт до сотен мегабайт

Comment: Выгрузка http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258160/unloading-the-assembly-loaded-with-assembly-loadfrom

Comment: Попробуйте ещё такой вариант http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo (FileVersionInfo Class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть класс: Version. И у этого класса есть оператор сравнения.

```
Version first = new Version("1.1.2.1");
Version second = new Version("2.1.1.1");
bool b = first >= second;
```

У каждого файла есть информация о файле. Та которую ты видишь выбрав "свойства" в контекстном меню.

Вот так достается информация о версии файла по адресу на локальном диске через FileVersionInfo (на примере блокнота):

```
var notepadFileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "Notepad.exe"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, зависит от версии вашей dotNET библиотеки, но формально, любой файл должен содержать свою версию. Как уже писали выше -

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "filename.exe"));
```

Допустим, можешь создать переменную, содержащую номер прошлой версии и сравнивать с данной, а там уже делаешь что нужно конкретно тебе. Удачи!